# A RenderFlex overflowed by 17 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter

[image]

The Render Box is the porblem as the image show below :)
I have a problem with the trailing Column
When i reduce the container height to 30 the overflowed is gone but i wanna make this text fit with others devices without render Box :)

- So how can i fix this in the same i can run it in multiple devices

  ```
   ListView.separated(
                           separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                                 color: ColorManager.lightGrey,
                               ),
                           itemCount: value.transfersModel!.data!.length,
                           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                             var data = value.transfersModel!.data![index];
                             return ListTile(
                               leading: IconButton(
                                   onPressed: () {},
                                   icon: Icon(Icons.copy_sharp)),
                               title: Text("${data.office!.name}"),
                               subtitle: Text("${data.recipientName}"),
                               trailing: Column(
                                 mainAxisAlignment:
                                     MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                 children: [
                                   FittedBox(
                                     child: Container(
                                       child: ButtonTheme(
                                         alignedDropdown: true,
                                         child: DropdownButton(
                                           dropdownColor:
                                               ColorManager.white,
                                           icon: Icon(
                                             Icons
                                                 .keyboard_arrow_down_outlined,
                                             color: ColorManager.lightGrey
                                                 .withOpacity(0.51),
                                           ),
                                           underline: Container(),
                                           items: value.transfersStatus
                                               .map((item) {
                                             print(
                                                 "${item.keys.single} : ${item.values.single} ${data.status.toString()}");
                                             return new DropdownMenuItem(
                                                 child: new Text(
                                                   item.values.single
                                                       .toString(),
                                                   style: TextStyle(
                                                     fontSize: 13.0,
                                                   ),
                                                 ),
                                                 value: item.keys.single
                                                     .toString());
                                           }).toList(),
                                           value: data.status.toString(),
                                           onChanged: (String? value) {
                                             setState(() {
                                               data.status = value;
                                             });
                                           },
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                       height: 50.h,
                                       padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                           color: ColorManager
                                               .tabBarBackground,
                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                               Radius.circular(5))),
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                   Text(
                                     "${data.createdAt}".replaceHHMMa(),
                                     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.sp),
                                   )
                                 ],
                               ),
                             );
                           }),
  ```

Comment: please add images to better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your column children with `Expanded Widget` one by one and add flex to it

Answer (score 1):

You can increase height of ListView component by using `padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),` property of ListView.separated, it will allow spacing between 2 widgets. And you can also use separatorBuilder for separation between 2 data.

```
  separatorBuilder: (c, index) {
       return SizedBox(height: 10);
   },
```